# Using AudioUnit AUConverter to upsample causes the playback speed to increase

Tags: ios, audio, ios7, core-audio, audiounit

My current AUGraph is set up as Mixer unit->remoteIO unit on an iOS platform. I am using the mixer to mix two mono stream into stereo interleaved.Everything works fine when the sample rates of the streams and the hardware match i.e 44100. When the sample rate of the mono streams is different, than the hardware sample rate I am initializing the graph as Mixer unit(mixes two mono 8k streams)->AUconverter(upsamples to hardware sample rate i.e 44100)->remoteIO. The problem is when the output plays for the modified graph the play rate increases along with pitch shift.  How can I maintain the playback speed when i am upsampling ??

Comment: can you add some code if it's not too long? or a link to a sample project?